# How was the helicopter scene from Captain America: Civil War filmed?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, film-techniques, effects, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War (2016)* there is one scene where *Captain America prevents a helicopter from flying away with his bare hands*.

Here is that scene if you haven't watched the movie, or want to see it again:

**How was this scene filmed?**

Comment: I think the real question is: how did he drag that helicopter down in the first place?  The (get in the) chopper would've had more than enough lift to just carry on with Capt. hanging off the side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The helicopter is CGI while Chris Evans acts against a green screen on a motion control rig.

He grabs a controlled "helicopter" landing strut attached to the rig..and the rest is done in the computer.

[image]

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Thanks..was just about to fix that.

Comment: No problem, so many "Chris" in hollywood that it makes you confused xD